# Insert text in a column without breaking spacing

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

So I have a file filled with lines like this:

```
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   mode=35        0 0
```

I'm trying to add some text (we'll call it `ADD`) 4th column so that the output is

```
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /                       ext3    defaultsADD        1 1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaultsADD        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   mode=35ADD        0 0
```

I've tried both `sed` and `awk`
**`SED`**:

```
$ sed -r 's/(\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+)(\s+\S+\s+\S$)/\1ADD\2/' fstab
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /                       ext3    defaultsADD        1 1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaultsADD        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   mode=35ADD        0 0
```

This works perfectly but that `sed` is disgusting to look at
**`AWK`**:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{$4=$4"ADD"; print}' fstab 
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00        /       ext3    defaultsADD        1       1
LABEL=/boot     /boot   ext3    defaultsADD        1       2
tmpfs   /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaultsADD        0       0
```

While the command itself is readable, the output loses the original spacing, which I want to preserve.

So I see three possible solutions to my problem:

- A better looking `sed` command
- A way to use `awk` that will preserve the spacing
- Some other nice (short, readable) looking command that preserves the spacing (perhaps `perl`)

---

EDIT:
I would like this to be an **in-place edit (overwrite `fstab`)**.
Using `sed -i'' -r 's/...` works but I haven't a good way for `awk` to handle in-place edits. I know I could just output it to a file and overwrite `fstab` with it, but that's a bit long (`awk ... > temp && mv -f temp fstab`), and I'm going for short here.

Comment: If all you want is nice columns and not that exact spacing then piping that `awk` output to `column -t` will get that for you.

Comment: @EtanReisner I never knew about `column` so thanks for that! Unfortunately I'm looking for a quick in-place edit and I don't think that will work.

Comment: recent GNU awk releases have `awk -i inplace '...' file` to do psedudo-inplace editing like sed does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's arguable whether or not this sed is pretty but it works.

```
sed -r 's/((\s+\S+){3})/\1ADD/' fstab
```

Edit: Fixed it and it's a little better to look at.

Comment: Used it with `sed -i'' -r...` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: It may not be a problem, but this will break if any of the lines in the file have leading whitespace.

Comment: It'll modify comments too.

Comment: @skamazin, `-i''` is the same as just `-i`

Answer (score 2):

Slightly less ugly regex with Perl:

```
perl -i.bak -pwe 'next if /^#/; s/^(?:\S+\s+){3}\S+\K/ADD/' /etc/fstab
```

Note that the `\K` escape was added in Perl 5.10. Comment lines are skipped since I'm assuming you don't want to add anything to them. The `-i` flag does an in-place edit, saving a copy of the original to `/etc/fstab.bak`.

Comment: Some how my version (5.8.8) doesn't recognize the kill pattern (`\K`).

Comment: As I said in the answer, `\K` (for "keep", not "kill") was added in Perl 5.10.

Comment: Ah I see, while this is a beautiful piece of `perl` (+1), I can't use it.

Comment: There are alternatives along the same lines as [Cody Probst's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25166493/176646) that will work for Perl 5.8, but you should really consider upgrading...Perl 5.10 was released almost seven years ago.

Comment: @skamazin, `s/^((?:\S+\s+){3}\S+)/${1}ADD/` would be the pre-5.10 solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is it again with sed:

```
sed -r 's|((\s+\S+){3})(.*)|\1ADD\2|' /etc/fstab
```

It repeats the `\s+\S+` pattern three times and puts that result into `\1`, and then captures everything after it with `.*` and puts that into `\2`.

Comment: Not quite right, it actually re-prints `default`: `$  sed -r 's|((\s+\S+){3})(.*)|\1ADD\2|' /etc/fstab
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /                       ext3    defaultsADD    defaults
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaultsADD    defaults
`

Comment: I fixed that. `\2` should be `\3`

Answer (score 1):

`awk '{gsub($4, $4"ADD"); print}' fstab` seems to work for me.

Comment: An in-place edit is just a cp/mv unless you write to the same fh as you read. Which I don't believe any of these tools actually do. They just hide that from you with an argument.

Comment: @skamazin Fair enough I suppose.

Comment: You can make this inplace by using GNU awk with `-i inplace` BUT I wouldn't use this solution anyway as it's using `$4` as an RE to match across the whole line. Imagine $4 was `foo` and $1 contained `foobar` - this solution would change $1 to `fooADDbar` in addition to modifying $4.

Comment: @EdMorton has a good point. It would be possible to make this at least somewhat safer but the accepted `sed` answer is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Your solutions seem good. What only lacks is the formatting. Use `column -t` for that.

```
... | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like the `sed` otherwise but find it unattractive, maybe a slight refactoring is all you really need.

```
f='\s+\S+'
sed -i.bak -r "s/($f$f$f)($f$f$)/\1ADD\2/" fstab
```

Answer (score 0):

You may like this Perl solution. The second line in the loop allows for lines that begin with whitespace, and may not need to be as complex.

It expects the path to the input file as a paramater on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  my @fields = split /(\s+)/;
  $fields[/^\S/ ? 6 : 8] .= 'ADD';
  print @fields;
}
```

**output**

```
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /                       ext3    defaultsADD        1 1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaultsADD        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   mode=35ADD        0 0
```